# ant build directory not setting properly

Tags: ant

I have the following structure in my file directory

```
build/
    mainfolder/
    ANTFILE_A
    subfolder1/
        ANTFILE_B
        subfolder2/
            ANTFILE_C
```

In the main subdirectory I have created ANTFILE_A where I have several targets that call on the targets inside of ANTFILE_B. For the most part, the targets all work, except for one case that I can't seem to understand why.

In ANTFILE_A I have the following:

```
<target name="clean-subfoler1" description="Cleans subdirectories">
    <ant dir="${subfolder1-dir}" antfile="antfile_b.xml" target="clean"/>
</target>
```

Within the subfolder 1 directory I have an antfile with a clean target that cleans up some of the other subdirectores like `subfolder2`. When I call the ant clean target from within the `subfolder1` directory, everything works correctly, no issues.

The issue comes when I try calling the target command shown above from ANTFILE_A in my mainfolder.

I keep getting and issue like this:

```
Invalid file: D:\build\mainfolder\subfolder2\antfile_c.xml
```

So whats happening is that for some reason when I call the clean command from antfile_a it seems to be skipping the subfolder1 directory and looking for subfolder2 from within the main directory. The issue is that subfolder2 is nested under subfolder1.

Now I have tested to see if the `basedir` was set properly, and it actually is et correctly to `D:\build\mainfolder\subfolder1` for that specific target.

This is how I set the subdirectory folder

I'd like to be able to get this target to work without having to change any property within the sub antfiles. I've tried looking at inheritAll, but none of that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question, I believe that maybe your ant is deleting your file before you call your target as antfile_c.xml

The ant file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <project name="Demo" default="clean-subfoler1" basedir=".">

    <property name="subfolder1-dir" value="**path to subfolder1**"/>

    <target name="clean-subfoler1" description="Cleans subdirectories">
        <ant dir="${subfolder1-dir}" antfile="antfileB.xml" target="clean"/>
    </target>
    </project>
```

The antfile 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <project name="Demo" default="clean" basedir=".">

    <property name="subfolder2-dir" value="**path to subfolder2**"/>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans subdirectories">
        <echo message="in antfileB"/>
          <echo message="delete files in subFolder2"/>
          <delete file="antfileC.xml"/>
          <echo message="delete directory subFolder2"/>
          <delete dir="${subfolder2-dir}"/>
    </target>

    </project>
```

When I run the ant:

```
 clean-subfoler1:

clean:
     [echo] in antfileB
     [echo] delete files in subFolder2
   [delete] Deleting: **path to** /mainfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/antfileC.xml
     [echo] delete directory subFolder2
   [delete] Deleting directory **path to**/mainfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

To get your error I have to delete the file first , than try to target it:

```
clean-subfoler1:

clean:
     [echo] in antfileB
     [echo] delete files in subFolder2
   [delete] Deleting: **path to**/mainfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/antfileC.xml
     [echo] call the file

BUILD FAILED
**path to**/mainfolder/antfileA.xml:7: The following error occurred while executing this line:
**path to**/mainfolder/subfolder1/antfileB.xml:11: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: **path to**/mainfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/antfileC.xml (No such file or directory)
```